# Issues with writing custom Excel function using Worksheet functions

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to excel-vba programming and I was learning how to write a custom vba function using worksheet function.

If I go to a cell and type in the following formula, I will get the cell name.

```
=ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN(), 4)
```

E.g., If we enter the above formula into cell "A6", the cell will return the value = `A6`

Now I am trying to write a vba function to do the exact same thing as following:

```
Function GetThisCellName() As String
    GetThisCellName= WorksheetFunction.Address(WorksheetFunction.Row(), WorksheetFunction.Column(), 4)       
End Function
```

However when I am trying to use this function inside a cell as follows:

```
=GetThisCellName()
```

the cell will return `#VALUE!`. What might be wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return address of cell, *from which formula was called*, use [Application.ThisCell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834969%28v=office.15%29.aspx):

```
Function GetThisCellName() As String
    GetThisCellName = Application.ThisCell.Address(False, False)
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

`Address`, `Row`, and `Column` are not members of [WorksheetFunction object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822194%28v=office.15%29.aspx). You can use this syntax to get the address of the cell:

```
Function GetThisCellName() As String
    GetThisCellName = ActiveCell.Address(False, False, xlA1)
End Function
```

See also [Range.Address property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837625%28v=office.15%29.aspx)